# Apply ignore where clause when no results are coming back

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

We have a SQL Select query which does something like the following:

```
SELECT    TOP 10
          Product.ProductItemID ,
          Product.ProductCode ,
          Product.ProductName ,
          Product.ProductGroupItemID,
          ...Other Columns...
FROM      Product
          ...Other Joins...
LEFT JOIN Stock
     ON   Stock.ProductItemID = Product.ProductItemID
WHERE     ProductGroupItemID = 12345
      AND ProductCode like 'ABC%'
      ...Other Criteria...
```

The business has asked for the following:

1. If Stock exists for the criteria sent in then only show the products that have stock
2. If no records have stock for the criteria sent in then show any product that meets the criteria

   The first criteria we can meet easily by putting in `HAVING SUM (Stock.BaseQuantity) > 0` and `group by` all of the columns in the select.

The problem is we only want to apply that if any of the products that meet the criteria have stock. If all of the products do not have stock then we want to not apply it.

How can we change the having clause to only apply when it will return a result?

Comment: What's wrong with having two separate independent queries? Run first query, check how many rows it returns. If there are no rows run second query. You can put this logic into the client or into the stored procedure on the server.

Comment: Certainly possible and nothing wrong with it, just wondering if there was a another way

Comment: "Better" means faster? If the logic is such that you have to run the first query any way, then it may be faster to have two explicit simple queries for which there are optimal indexes, rather than one complex query, for which it would be difficult for the optimizer to find a good plan. The `IF` operator may be embedded into the query using `CASE`, but in any case, I don't understand the required logic enough to suggest anything specific. Could you show some sample data and expected result of the query to illustrate the required logic? I don't promise to give an answer, but others could.

Comment: "Better" as in it works better for our system without a significant speed hit. All of our search pages currently work the same way and only run one query. For maintainability we'd like to keep doing the same on this page too. It's the first time in about 5 years the business requirement for search pages hasn't worked in 1 query.